# jQuery toggle doesn't work properly if no display property set initially

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm using jQuery v1.8.3 and jQuery UI v1.9.2.

On a `click` of a `button` I wish a menu (via a `ul`) to hide if it's open, or show if it's closed, so I chose to use the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function in it's most basic form, on `click`, `toggle()`. Simple as that, e.g.

```
button.click =>
  autocomplete = input_field.data("ui-autocomplete")
  menu = autocomplete.menu
  ul = menu.element
  ul.toggle()
```

(it's coffeescript, but you get the gist)

What actually happens is that when the `ul` is displayed at first (not via the button) it has <strike>display property set</strike> the display property set to `display: block`.

Then, on first click of the button if I check within the click function what the current status of the display property is via:

```
console.log "display = #{ul.css('display')}"
ul.toggle()
console.log "display = #{ul.css('display')}"
```

the output is:

> display = none
>   display = block

So for some reason the property is being incorrectly picked up initially.

<strike>it adds the display property as `display: block` and then on the next click sets `display: none`.</strike>

I'm not in control of the `ul` directly as it is rendered by the [autocomplete widget](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) and I'm not keen on having to fiddle about with that.

Is this expected behaviour, and what is the best way to work around this? I'm thinking of passing a function to `click` that checks if there is a display attr set and then show or hide dependent on that, but if there's an easier way or better function, maybe a newer version of toggle, then please let me know. The jQuery docs are, in my view, some of the worst of any tech project so I consider it quite likely that I'm using the wrong function entirely.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's open source and it's called hacking. Actually, I'm adding a button that opens the drop down menu with all the possible options. There is a [combobox demo that doesn't really work](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html) with several implementations that either also don't work or don't do what I wish.

Answer (score 0):

Set the display attribute on page load. Something like

```
$(function(){
  $("ul").hide();
});
```

once the autocomplete is rendered.

This will set display:none use `.show()` to make it `display:block`

Comment: I've updated my question as I've found new info and I may have been incorrect about the initial state of the display property (though I can't be sure now, but probably!:S). I also can't set the display on page load as the menu is built via the autocomplete widget, which sets it to `display: none` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`toggle` should work even if your element doesn't have a display property explicitly set. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zSbN5/1/) for an example. One thing to check is that you're doing the click handler in `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: I've updated my question as I've found new info and I may have been incorrect about the initial state of the display property (though I can't be sure now, but probably!:S). The click handler is definitely covered by the jQuery function context.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you see the li when the page first loads, if that is expected behavior then great - it shouldn't matter either way. I created this JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r0k3t/Rcpet/ Go there and try it, whether the CSS sets the display property to block or none when you first load the page the toggle works just fine. If you had posted more code it would be easier to see what you want to accomplish but it's hard to know where the issue is just from your description, you could have a simple syntax error but we can't see that. Anyway - here is the same code that is on JS fiddle.

```
<a href="#" id="toggleButton">Toggle li element</a>
    <ul>
        <li>You can see me now</li>
    </ul>

//Here is the JS wired up in document load
function toggleLi() {
    $("ul li").toggle();
}

$("#toggleButton").click(toggleLi);

/* Here is the CSS */
ul li {
 display: block;  /*change to none and test - works as well */  
}
```

Comment: There's no syntax error because I'm using coffeescript to compile it, it checks the syntax for me. There is no `li` initially because it's an autocomplete widget, there is however a `ul` with display set to none. When the menu appears, display is set to block.

Comment: I've updated the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r0k3t/Rcpet/1/ I am able to toggle the ul that is created by the jQuery UI autocomplete. I must be missing something, maybe that will help though.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("ul").toggle();
  });

});
</script>
<style>
ul {display:none;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<ul>
<li>aaaa </li>
<li>bbbb </li>
<li>ccccccc </li>
</ul>



</body>
</html>
```